# Accessing Elasticsearch Docker instance using NEST

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, nest

I run a simple Elasticsearch instance using Docker Compose:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.1
    hostname: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1g
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.1.1
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: "0.0.0.0"
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
```

I can access it from browser using localhost, however when I run my application and connect to it, I'm experiencing some issues. From what I was able to track it seems that application successfully connects to Elasticsearch instance, then resolves IP it is bound to and then uses that IP address to communicate with Elasticsearch instance.

From Fiddler:

1. http://10.0.75.2:9200/_nodes/http,settings?flat_settings&timeout=2s
2. It returns a json that has the following line: `"host": "172.18.0.4"`
3. Then it tries to use this IP address and my requests fail because it cannot resolve that IP address

What should I change in order to be able to successfully connect to my Elasticsearch instance from C# application?

NEST version: 5.5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(Note: this answer uses NEST 7.1.0 and Elasticsearch 7.2.0, but the underlying concept is the same).**

`SniffingConnectionPool` will use the [`http.publish_address` of the node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings) when seeded in the connection pool. This means that the http publish address must be reachable by the client. If it's not explicitly set, it'll use the value from `http.host`, which if not set, will use the `network.host`, which will be the address on the private network.

With a docker compose configuration like

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "http.port=9200"
      - "http.publish_host=_local_"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "http.port=9201"
      - "http.publish_host=_local_"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9201
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

`es01` node is mapped to `localhost:9200` and `es02` to `localhost:9201`. We could have just specified that `es02` runs in the container on 9200, and mapped this to the host port of 9201, but the problem with doing this is that `es02`'s http.publish_address would still be `127.0.0.1:9200`, which is what the `SniffingConnectionPool` will end up using when seeding the node. To avoid this, we run `es02` on a different port to `es01`, so that the http publish addresses will be different.

With the above configuration, `http://localhost:9200/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.http` returns

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "CSWncVnxS1esOm1KQtOR3A": {
      "http": {
        "bound_address": ["0.0.0.0:9200"],
        "publish_address": "127.0.0.1:9200",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes": 104857600
      }
    },
    "rOAp0T57TgSI_zU1L-T-vw": {
      "http": {
        "bound_address": ["0.0.0.0:9201"],
        "publish_address": "127.0.0.1:9201",
        "max_content_length_in_bytes": 104857600
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(*node names will be different if you try this*). Now, `SniffingConnectionPool` will work

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "posts";
    var uris = new[]
    {
        new Uri("http://localhost:9200"),
        new Uri("http://localhost:9201")
    };

    var pool = new SniffingConnectionPool(uris);

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var response = client.Nodes.Info();

    foreach (var node in response.Nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{node.Key} http publish_address is: {node.Value.Http.PublishAddress}");
    }
}
```

prints

```
CSWncVnxS1esOm1KQtOR3A http publish_address is: 127.0.0.1:9200
rOAp0T57TgSI_zU1L-T-vw http publish_address is: 127.0.0.1:9201
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve it by simply changing `SniffingConnectionPool` to `StaticConnectionPool` on my setup.

Comment: Good you got it sorted. `SniffingConnectionPool` sniffs for the nodes in the cluster to determine which nodes it can send requests to, using the `publish_address`, or the first `bound_address` if there's no `publish_address`, as the address to use to make requests to the cluster: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/03ca71abe8df78b7eb43cd3bf0af40259c4fdb86/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Responses/Sniff/SniffResponse.cs#L40-L58.

Comment: Yep. When I asked the question then I remembered that there is more than one connection pool that I could use. Went to documentation and found what you have said. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Thank you @EvaldasBuinauskas, I've been cursing docker and NEST all morning.