# Elasticsearch client can't connect elasticsearch in docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch inside a container from a Java app which is also inside a container. Without docker containers my app correctly connect to local elasticsearch. My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

volumes:
  postgis:

services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    build:
      postgis/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./postgis:/var/lib/postgresql:rw
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - net

  application:
    depends_on:
      - database
      - es
    container_name: application
    build:
      application/
    ports:
      - $LORRYAPP_DEBUG_PORT:8080
    volumes:
      - ./application:/app:rw
    environment:
      LORRYAPP_OPTS: $LORRYAPP_OPTS
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - net

  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    networks:
      - net

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
```

Initialising es-client in ctor:

```
public ElasticSearchDao(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    this.esClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create("http://localhost:9200")));
    this.mapper = mapper;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:788) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.4.0.jar!/:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:218) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.4.0.jar!/:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:205) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.4.0.jar!/:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar!/:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1424) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar!/:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1394) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar!/:7.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:836) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar!/:7.4.0]
```

ES available through browser. http://0.0.0.0:9200/, http://127.0.0.1:9200/, http://localhost:9200/ give response:

```
{
  "name" : "254bdb7bcc2a",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "vm537RNGSiG3dW8ag2MDTw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "aa751e09be0a5072e8570670309b1f12348f023b",
    "build_date" : "2020-02-29T00:15:25.529771Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: It’s not localhost if you’re talking cross containers. Docker networking well resolve the container name so `es` in your case

Comment: Url should be set to `http://es:9200` for the inter-container communication.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be related to question I've asked a long while ago.

[Accessing Elasticsearch Docker instance using NEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006720/accessing-elasticsearch-docker-instance-using-nest)

It's targeted against C#, this is really an issue with containers. What happened in my case was that client would connect to docker, obtain internal IP which is used for inter-container communication only and then would try to use this IP to keep connection open - that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: So what did you *do*?

Comment: @SriniMurthy have you read the question I've linked here? ;)